# Javascript random text fade out / in

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, transition, fadeout

I have some text that randomly changes every 3 seconds, it is working like a charm but i want to make whenever it changes there is a fade out, fade in transition. This is my script/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textarray = [
    "& prisioner 24601.",
    "& occasional timelord.",
    "& part-time Pokémon trainer.",
    "& guilty for the zombie apocalypse.",
    "& potential book worm."    // No comma after last entry
];

function RndText() {
    var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
    document.getElementById('random_text').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
}
onload = function() { RndText(); }
var inter = setInterval(function() { RndText(); }, 3000);
```

and this is the html part it is applied to:

```
<span id="random_text">& occasional time lord</span>
```

Any idea on how to make this happen?
Thank you

Comment: please encode HTML strings properly: `& -> &amp;`

Comment: @BenM because the last time I checked it was written into the specification...

Comment: @Emissary corrected it on the code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged this post with `jquery`, you can easily achieve this using jQuery's own [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functions.

For example, your code can be updated as follows:

```
var textarray = [
    "& prisioner 24601.",
    "& occasional timelord.",
    "& part-time Pokémon trainer.",
    "& guilty for the zombie apocalypse.",
    "& potential book worm."
];

function RndText() 
{
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);

    $('#random_text').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
        $(this).text(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast');
    });
}

$(function() {
    // Call the random function when the DOM is ready:
    RndText(); 
});

var inter = setInterval(function() { RndText(); }, 3000);
```

I also made some slight changes to your code (such as changing `window.onload` to `$(document).ready()`).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jQUDB/)

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ePdk5/)</kbd>

```
var $ryt = $('#random_text');
function RndText() {
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
    $ryt.html(textarray[rannum]).hide().fadeIn('slow');
}
```